# GWT Window Manager (GWM). Security? Reliability? Alternatives?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-mvc

Doing a code review I've stumbled over [GWM](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwindowmanager/) in Java-Spring-GWT web-application. As this product was unknown to me, I went to it's website and became aware that it's development seemingly stopped in 2007, as it's last stable version is 0.6.6. Also no obvious activity after 2008 on the project pages. So, I wonder if it's safe and/or wise to use this product. I'd like to here opinions of those who has experience with this product. Also I'll be very grateful for replacement suggestions. We're a small company, so I can consider only free alternatives. For one I've found that SmartGWT has an LGPL option, which suites us well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we removed GWM related code and replaced it with custom written widgets.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GWT downloads page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/versions.html), GWT was on version 1.4-rc1 when GWM-0.6.6 was released. A lot has changed in GWT since then. Based on that fact alone, I would say GWM is probably not the wisest of choices.

That said, I've previously never heard of GWM, nor do I have any replacement solutions for you.